# Navigated HTMLdocument capture VBA

Tags: vba, dom

I am trying to automate data population for a webpage . The webpage auto-generates a generic id and I have to automate filling of data in the newly generated page

This is what I have done so far

```
Dim IE as InternetExplorerMedium
Dim doc as HTMLdocument

Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

IE.Visible = True
IE. Navigate sURL

Do While IE.Busy
     Application.Wait DateAdd(“s”,1, Now)
Loop

Set doc = IE.document
doc.getElementbyId(“generate_new_record”).Click
```

Here I will be generated a new page

However by IE and doc variables are still have the instance of the first page

How can I get it to be set to the new page

Comment: `Set doc = IE.document` after each new page is loaded

Comment: I have tried this it doesnt work

Comment: I've never seen that not work.